# Image manipulation program using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Hi all hope you can direct me to the right direction.
I want to implement an application which performs many different operations to a picture.  As an example, rotate, crop, highlight, soft focus, zoom, etc.  I would like this application to perform as close to winforms as possible without the constant flicker of a page in ASP.  Can someone direct me to the right direction?  I started reading AJAX.  Is that where I should start?  Are there any tools i can purchase to accomplish this task?  I am new to AJAX and picture manipulation on the web.
Thanks

Comment: Is this a classic ASP question, or ASP.NET? The title says ASP.NET, but you tagged it as classic ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will give you something to start with http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6620/ASP-NET-Image-Manipulation-Examples-Adding-Zooming and just now I am going through found this which is free for both personal and commercial use http://piczard.com/download/

Comment: Thanks.  Interesting that i received 2 negative votes.  I am trying to implement this functionality and not sure why would anyone give a negative vote.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: you're welcome.If the negative votes are given then there are many reasons you may ind it here http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down